# How can I find a way to import only a few Vuetify components to project based on Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

How can I find a way to import only a few Vuetify components to project based on Nuxt?
Without any other components or global CSS files

I am trying to do that with official docs
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#manually-importing

But got an error

Details:

```
// plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify, { VCard, VRating, VToolbar } from 'vuetify/lib'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VCard,
    VRating,
    VToolbar,
  },
  directives: {
    Ripple,
  },
})

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)


// nuxt.config.js
plugins: ['@/plugins/vuetify.js'],
```

Error screen
[image]

Comment: Tree shaking is not required in NUXT, It is taken care of by the framework.